# How to toggle Caps Lock status on remote Windows system?

Tags: keyboard, remote-desktop, vnc, capslock

Sometimes people turned on the Caps Lock on a remote Windows system which is running VNC service. When I connect to the remote system through VNC Viewer, the Caps Lock status on the local and remote machines is inverted. Everything that I typed would be in CAPITAL letter despite my local machine has not turned on the Caps Lock. I have to toggle Caps Lock on local machine in order to get the correct letter in remote system. Even though that works but it is an annoyance especially when working on system that is caps sensitive.

Is there a way to toggle the Caps Lock status on remote system without physically in front of the "remote" system?

Comment: This appears to be a question that contains the answer. Please [edit] so that it is a question and then you may write an answer to it.

Comment: This is the greatest question ever asked.

Answer (score 16):

I came across a fix/workaround by [Ray Rajko Bogdanovic's reply](http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/197034-is-there-a-way-to-turn-caps-lock-off-remotely).

Ray suggested to use the **On-Screen Keyboard**.

Follow the steps below to toggle the Caps Lock status:

- Press Windows key and type keyboard.
- Click Caps Lock (on On-Screen Keyboard) to toggle the status.
- Close On-Screen keyboard software.

This should work for other keys as well.

Answer (score 5):

I'm using a Mac to remotely access a Windows machine. I just discovered that I am able to turn the remote desktop's Caps Lock on and off using "alt+Capslock" on my Mac.

Comment: My remote windows PC intermittently gets stuck in capslock, while the local one still toggles on and off fine.  I've been  trying to find a solution for two years , and now I find this 8yo answer and it immediately solves my problem!

Alt-Capslock!!!  I love you Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007

Answer (score 2):

Basically this is a modification of @jooguan [answer above](https://superuser.com/a/828439/130607).

The trick of *pressing Windows key and type keyboard*, didn't work for me remotely.

So I used literally the same suggestion of [Ray Rajko Bogdanovic's](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/post/1179552) to use the **On-Screen Keyboard**, following these steps:

- Connect to the remote machine
- In the remote Windows system, click the *[Start button](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Start_menu#Start_button)*, located in [Windows Taskbar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taskbar#Microsoft_Windows)
- Go to *Accessories* > *Ease of Access* / or *Accessibility* sub folder
- Open Microsoft *[On-Screen Keyboard](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/10762/windows-use-on-screen-keyboard)* software
- Click *Caps Lock* (key in remote *On-Screen Keyboard*) to toggle the remote keyboard status (unlock caps).
- Close *On-Screen keyboard* software.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Caps Lock](http://www.georgejopling.co.uk/capslock/capslock.html) utility program by [George Jopling](http://www.georgejopling.co.uk/) to turn on/off Caps Lock using mouse control for Windows.

*Setup will place a shortcut link in the all users startup folder (Windows 7, Vista and XP) so that when you start the computer Caps Lock will run automatically.*

[image]

By default Caps Lock is turned off.

Comment: Unfortunately that website is now offline. Updated link https://download.cnet.com/Caps-Lock/3000-2094_4-75951411.html

Answer (score 1):

To access remotely Windows-10 the easiest solution I found is to get the virtual keyboard in this way. Click the red marked icon on the bottom right corner of the screen.

[image]

Then select "Virtual keyboard", the computer I am accessing now is in Italian but the position of the option should be the same in other languages.

[image]

After that it is really easy to get rid of the Caps lock, whatever keyboard you are using.