# How to manipulate the keyboard flags under windows?

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-layout

My caps lock key is remapped. How do I disable the `caps is active` flag under windows?

I remapped my caps lock key to Ctrl with the help of [ac'tivAid](http://www.heise.de/ct/activaid/) and its extension RemapKeys.

When my PC is overloaded the keyboard works like when the extension isn't active, so that caps lock works as caps lock, I can sometimes activate the normally disabled key. When I later type my letters get capitalized.

Does anyone know of a windows method similar to the linux command "[setleds -caps](https://superuser.com/a/419855/266193)" so I can disable my caps lock flag after my computer becomes responsive again?

I think I tried a on-screen keyboard like in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/828439/266193) but that got catched by the ac'tivAid extension also.

I just tried to remap the key for Windows via the registry, but isn't there any command, WinAPI call or 3rd-party tool to manipulate the keyboard flags?

[caps_lock_to_control.reg](http://johnhaller.com/useful-stuff/disable-caps-lock)

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"Scancode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,02,00,00,00,1d,00,3a,00,00,00,00,00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dropped the Windows Registry manipulation and instead used an AutoHotkey script I found while researching:

```
/* 
 CapsLock einzeln gedrückt als ESC, mit Taste als Ctrl.
; Author: fwompner gmail com
*/
#InstallKeybdHook
SetCapsLockState, alwaysoff
Capslock::
SetCapsLockState, alwaysoff
Send {LControl Down}
KeyWait, CapsLock
Send {LControl Up}
if ( A_PriorKey = "CapsLock" )
{
    Send {Esc}
}
return
```

The first comment line translates to "A press and release of CapsLock emits a ESC keypress, while holding CapsLock and pressing a normal key acts as if Control was pressed."